# Access QT Widget child members from QT Widget Object Instance

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qtwidgets

Consider this `QWidget` initialized as:

```
QWidget *Logger;
Logger = new QWidget();

QPushButton *btn;
btn= new QPushButton(Logger);
btn->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton"));

Logger->show();
```

It display the Logger with a button with text pushButton.
Now Later if i want to access pushButton, i do it like this:

```
QPushButton *pushButton = Logger->findChild<QPushButton *>("pushButton");
pushButton->setText("NEW BUTTON");
```

I want to know is there a possibility to access directly this pushButton from `Logger`??
Something like:

```
Logger->btn ...
```

I tried but it does not work. I have Widgets defined like this with many child objects and i wonder is this the only way to access them at run time??

EDIT: @drescherjm, So something along these lines you mean:

```
class MyWidget : QWidget
{

public:
    QPushButton *pushButton;
    MyWidget(){
        pushButton = new QPushButton(this);
    }
};


MyWidget *w = new MyWidget();
w->pushButton->setText("XYZ");
```

And is it worth it to create so many classes?? for small redundant tasks?

Comment: Unless you can make a btn a class member of your `QWidget` derived type (instead of a plain QWidget) its not going to work the way you want. With that said I don't see the problem or difficulty with findChild<>. I use it hundreds of times in my code.

Comment: You mean I make a widget class and set btn as private member of it. and then setup layout with this btn, and so it will be accessible directly? Is it possible to give a pseudo code for this perhaps?

Comment: ***You mean I make a widget class and set btn as private member of it. and then setup layout with this btn, and so it will be accessible directly?*** Yes you can do that. The question is whether writing 50 to 100 lines of code is worthwhile versus just a few with findChild<>

Comment: ***And is it worth it to create so many classes?? for small redundant tasks?*** I think you will have to decide what is better for your situation. I don't fully understand why you are changing the text of buttons and why this would be a common thing.

Comment: is it a bureaucracy to keep rating negative just to satisfy your ego? i really don't understand that. If you are a beginner what do you expect? to be a superman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work the way that you are expecting it to work. Use `btn` as long as it is in scope.

If you are creating `btn` somewhere locally, but your use-case demands you to use it in different places across your code, then you need to reconsider your design and make the `QPushButton` part of a class member.

Something of this sort :

```
#include <QPushButton>

class SampleWidget : public QWidget
{
   public :
     SampleWidget( QWidget * inParent );
     // public methods to change the properties of the QPushButton go here.
     void SetButtonText( QString const & inString );
     bool IsButtonChecked();

   private :
     QPushButton *mSampleButton;
};
```

And in the implementation :

```
SampleWidget::SampleWidget(QWidget *parent)
  :
   mSampleButton( new QPushButton( parent ) )
{
   // connect( mSampleButton,......... ); Connection to slot
}

void SampleWidget::SetButtonText( QString const & inString )
{
   mSampleButton->setText( inString );
}

bool
SampleWidget::IsButtonChecked()
{
   return mSampleButton->isChecked();
}
```

The question was not very clear on what you exactly want, but it seems like you are struggling to understand how to alter the attributes of a push button if it is a private member of a class and the above example will help you with that.